# Why is Mi Yodeya written in Rashi script?

Tags: discussion, design, hebrew

I'd like to know why the hebrew for Mi Yodeya is written in Rashi script?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Possible use of Rashi script for the title text began in chat with Jin, the designer, [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/468?m=4239704#4239704):

> oh btw, feedback from a Jewish friend of mine:
>   "I think adding מי יודע (mi yode'a) in Hebrew to the logo might have a good effect on people. You might want to consider Rashi Script, both because it's more stylized and because some (very religious) people might think Hebrew is overstepping it (with the whole it being the language of the bible and so on)."

DoubleAA pointed out:

> As far as Rashi Script goes, for the 5 letters we are dealing with, there aren't really big differences.

HodofHod added:

> @Jin absolutely! Rashi script is also a good idea because it's used almost exclusively for learning and texts. So mix that with the Tree of Life, and you've got "Life" and "learning"

Further discussion about site design can be found in these bookmarked chats (all from Bam):

http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/468/conversation/jin-on-site-logo-design-1
http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/468/conversation/jin-on-site-logo-design-2
http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/468/conversation/jin-on-site-logo-design-3
http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/468/conversation/pre-meta-design-screening-with-jin

There were also discussions on meta.

Comment: maybe [meta-tag:faq]?